# How to update value of range slider with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
showActions(){
    return(
        <div className="action -bar">
            <button className="Button-Edit" onClick={()=>{this.setState({clickedCrop : true})}}> Crop </button> 
            <br/> 
            Brightness : <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value={val_brightness} onChange={() => {this.handleChange}}/>  
            <br/> 
            Blur :<input type="range" min="1" max="5" value={val_blur} onChange={() => {this.handleChange}}/>
            <br/>
            <button className="Button-Edit" onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag_grayscale :true})}}> Grayscale</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button className="Button-Edit" onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag_invert :true})}}> Invert </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the `onChange` method means [controlled input](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), so you need to use the `state` value to store the changed value, inside the `onchange` method update `state` value of respective `input` element, Check this example how to `change` slider value, run this snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
 
   constructor(){
       super();
       this.state = {
          val_brightness: '',
          val_blur: ''
       }
   }
   
   handleChange(e){
       let obj = {};
       obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
       this.setState(obj);
   }
   
   showActions(){
      return(
        <div className="action -bar"> 
            Brightness : <input type="range" min="0" max="1" name='val_brightness' value={this.state.val_brightness} onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}}/>  
            <br/> 
            Blur : <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value={this.state.val_blur} name='val_blur' onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}}/>
        </div>
      )
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
         this.showActions()
      )
   } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: This post is exactly what I needed. It contains the syntax you need for the onChange handler: `onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}`, then you just need to make that method, here's mine: `handleProfileScaleChange(e) { this.setState({ profileScale: Number(e.target.value) }) }`

Comment: `e.target.value` is the current value of the range slider.

Answer (score -2):

In react.js there are two ways to change state of components.
The recommended one is to make child component value prop dependent on parent's state and change state of your parent component which will lead to re-rendering of the whole component.

The hacky way is to change prop of the component directly using ref.

I'd recommend you to read react.js documentation thoroughly until you'll understand what I mean.